# how can i create virtual microphone driver by using Java?

Tags: java, audio, microphone, javasound

how can i create virtual microphone driver by using Java?

My problem is to create a program that work like virtual microphone device for let the another program like skype,msn to read sound input from the virtual device in state of real microphone. i need some suggestion or some sample source code for Java.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in pure Java because you would have to use operating system-specific native APIs to do this.

Comment: how about if i create it in windows. what tool i should use or some sample code.

Comment: Have you tried PortAudio? Its a C library and I haven't had much luck with it in Java but if you were to write a JNI wrapper for it that may provide the hardware or native control required for this sort of thing. PortAudio works in Linux too or for Linux you could try Alsa and I'm not familiar at all with Mac so you'd have to google that one. Hope that helped a little.